# js-objectdetect with LBP cascades

Tags: javascript, opencv, face-recognition, object-detection, lbph-algorithm

I´m developing currently a webapp with object detection using the [js-objectdetect](https://github.com/mtschirs/js-objectdetect/) libary. 
Therefore I´m converting [opencv HAAR-cascades](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/tree/master/data/haarcascades) to the needed js-objectdetect format with a [python script](https://gist.github.com/mtschirs/df8d8dc5ff56cc7187b1).

My question is, if it´s possible to convert [opencv LBP-cascades](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/tree/master/data/lbpcascades) to the js-objectdetect format too. I need this, because I already have an opencv application in use and I need to use the same LBP-cascades.

I don´t find anything on Javascript object-/ face detection with LBP-cascades on the internet. Does anybody know a way to use these cascades with js-objectdetect or some other libary?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Local binary patterns and HAAR features are very different from each other. [js-objectdetect](https://github.com/mtschirs/js-objectdetect) is highly optimized for fast HAAR cascade evaluation based on integral images and cannot handle LBP cascades.

However, it seems there are javascript solutions for LBP object detection available, a quick google search pointed me to https://github.com/LukaszKrawczyk/LBP

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I also found the posted Link myself, thank you too, but the code in the repository is not working.